# "Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency!" when importing "formBuilder" into a service

Tags: angular, angular-services, formbuilder

I have an Angular 9 service which is running fine. However, upon attempting to push my data into a form, i created a new form by adding the following into the service:

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

newForm = new FormGroup({});

this.newForm = formBuilder.group({
  value_one: [''],
  value_two: [''],
});
```

Any time `public formBuilder: FormBuilder` is added to any of my services, I receive the error:

> "Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency!"

If however, I decided to add those to the component.ts instead of the service, it's fine.

I've had this set up working fine in my Angular 8 project, so I'm wondering if anything has changed for A9 that I haven't noticed?

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: `this.newForm = formBuilder.group({
  value_one: [''],
  value_two: [''],
});` should be `this.newForm = this.formBuilder...`.

Comment: Yup, that was a typo for this question. Even if `this.newForm` isn't included and just the formBuilder added to the constructor, the error is received.

Comment: This may not be related to angular 9, here's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091872/angular-4-cannot-instantiate-cyclic-dependency-injectiontoken-http-interceptor)

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm not injecting another service and looping around as far as I can see. I have one component importing one service. That service works fine until a formBuilder is added. That's when it dies.

Comment: @Haven did you figure this out? I have the exact same problem having updated a project from Angular 8 to 10 and I just cant see a reason for it.